# Inject SpringBoot app version into buildspec.yml for AWS CodeBuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, aws-codebuild, aws-pipeline

I am using SpringBoot, gitflow-maven plugin, AWS CodeBuild and Github connector to deploy on changes to master branch.

Currently, each release branch requires manual setting of the `artifacts:files` to match the versioned jar name.

Can this be automated by injecting the version or artifact name? Or is there a best practice?

The `CODEBUILD_SOURCE_VERSION` env variable is availble, but docs show that for Github, this is either

> commit ID, branch name, or tag name associated with the version
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-env-vars.html

```
version: 0.2

phases:
  build:
    commands:
       - cd pipelinedemo
       - mvn install
       - echo $CODEBUILD_SRC_DIR
artifacts:
  base-directory: pipelinedemo/target
  files:
    - pipelinedemo-0.0.2.jar <- must be updated to 0.0.3 in next release branch
```